# How can I get an enum list and set selected value in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an enum and I'm Using this markup:

```
<select asp-for="Category" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<WebsiteInfoCategory>()" 
        class="form-control"></select>
```

But I want to set a selected item of this enum.

How can I do that?

When I get an enum it's hard to set selected Item of it. Please help solve this problem.

I need a way to set selected value in this code line.

Answer (score 0):

To select the value for select drop-down by default, you should initialize the default value for the `Category` field in your model in the controller action.

Assume your `WebsiteInfoCategory` enum is something like:

```cs
public enum WebsiteInfoCategory
{
    MemberOne,
    MemberTwo
}
```

```cs
public IActionResult YourPageView()
{
    YourModel model = new YourModel();
    model.Category = WebsiteInfoCategory.MemberOne;

    return View(model);
}
```

With the approach above, the rendered `<select>` element will add the `selected="selected"` behavior to the particular `<option>` element.

```
<select id="Category" name="Category">
   <option selected="selected" value="0">MemberOne</option>
   <option value="1">MemberTwo</option>
</select>
```

Reference: [The Select Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-select-tag-helper)